# Apply zoom event on existing SVG (d3.js v4)

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg, zooming

I try to make my SVG zoomable in d3.js (version 4).

You can see my attempt here : [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ghpo6ayo/2/)

**HTML**

```
<svg id="mySVG" width="800px" height="600px" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); background: lightgrey;">
  <g>
    <path d="M 0 0 L 100 0 L 100 20 L 0 20 Z" fill="red"></path>
    <path d="M 500 500 L 600 500 L 600 520 L 500 520" fill="green"></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    var svg = d3.select("#mySVG")
  .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
    svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.transform.x + " " + d3.event.transform.y + ") scale(" + d3.event.transform.k + ")");
  }));

  // For test purposes
  //$('#mySVG').css('transform', 'scale(2)');
});
```

In fact, all seems to work since when I check in the Google's code inspector, focusing on my SVG element, I see the value of translate and scale changing as I mousewheel forward/backward. But nothing happens to the actual element which is very strange since I also tryied to change those scaling/translating value through plain jQuery and the SVG responds by scaling correctly.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for this task ?

For the record, here is the official documentation for the [`d3.zoom()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/blob/master/README.md#zoom) function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are applying the **attribute** transform to your `svg`, this is not [valid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform).  In your jquery example, you are applying the **style** transform to your `svg`, this is valid.  The usual `d3` methodology is to wrap your zoomed area in a `g` and apply the attribute transform to that.  In addition you are missing a comma in your translate:

```
d3.event.transform.x + " " + d3.event.transform.y //<-- there should be a comma in there
```

Comment: Wrapping in a g and applying the transformation works now : [**JSFiddle Updated**](https://jsfiddle.net/ghpo6ayo/6/). Remains a bug, when I zoom on my path the zoom behaves correctly, but not when I mousewheel on the area of the `<g>` tag that does not include the path (but it is not the purpose of this question).

Comment: Edit : I had to bind `g.call(d3.drag().on('drag', function() { /* ... */ })));` before the scale to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Add an id to your g element, and apply zoom to it rather than the svg root